# How to configure multiple datasources with the single security policy in wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I have setup successfully two data sources using different encrypted password policies as follows:

**Security policy 1**

```
<security-domain name="policy1" cache-type="default">
     <authentication>
          <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
             <module-option name="username" value="user1"/>
             <module-option name="password" value="-16de44"/>
             <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=DATASOURCE_1"/>
          </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

**Security policy 2**

```
<security-domain name="policy1" cache-type="default">
     <authentication>
          <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
             <module-option name="username" value="user2"/>
             <module-option name="password" value="-16de44"/>
             <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=DATASOURCE_2"/>
          </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

**Datasource 1**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/DATASOURCE_1" pool-name="DATASOURCE_1" enabled="true"> 
       .
       .         
       <security>
           <security-domain>policy_1</security-domain>
        </security>
    </datasource>
```

**Datasource 2**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/DATASOURCE_2" pool-name="DATASOURCE_2" enabled="true">    
         .
         .      
        <security>
            <security-domain>policy_2</security-domain>
         </security>
</datasource>
```

However, I would like to know if it's possible to use the same policy for both datasources? I haven't been able to find a way to include more than one pool_name in the **managedConnectionFactoryName** policy attribute:

```
<module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=DATASOURCE_1 ??????, DATASOURCE_2 ?????"/>
```

Is the **managedConnectionFactoryName** attribute absolutely necessary? what could be a side effect if this attribute is not added?

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? https://access.redhat.com/solutions/304063

That means:

```
<module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:name=DS1,service=LocalTxCM</module-option>
<module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:name=DS2,service=LocalTxCM</module-option>
```

Comment: I had already seen that link and as you may have seen, you need an RedHat subscription to see the answer. The person asking the question was just guessing what to set the the <module-option>. It does not matter what you put in that configuration, Wildfly does not show any message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Wildfly 8.2 prefers this syntax:

```
<module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:name=DS1,service=LocalTxCM"/>
```

But, It still does not seem to honor the security-domain for more that one datasource.

Does anyone know the significance of

```
service=LocalTxCM
```

in the example above?  Seems like this would be different for xa-datasouces.